# I can't run my mongodb on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDB in my windows 7 64 bit, but this error keeps appearing when I run 'mongod' command on cmd. Can someone help me?

I already tried to reinstall, change the version, and change the install directory.

the error always shows this alert: "The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gRsX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (from https://www.thewindowsclub.com/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing):

## Repair installed Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package

Open Control Panel and go to “Programs and Features” section. Find out Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) [for 64-bit machine] > right-click on it > select Change button > click on the Repair button.

## Re-register the DLL file

If the DLL file is present on your computer, but you still receive this error message, you may need to [re-register the DLL file](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/register-dll-file-windows).

If the DLL file is missing, then downloading the [missing dll file](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-missing-dll-files-errors-windows) from the internet and pasting it to a particular place is not the actual solution. You can try that method, but you may not get any positive result from it.

## Update for Universal C Runtime

Download the Update for Universal C Runtime from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows). Install the Runtime component and restart your computer and see. Just for your information, starting with Windows 10, the Universal CRT is part of the operating system.

## Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Update

If this does not help, you may need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-package) Update from [Microsoft here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=52685). You need to select the OS architecture, i.e. 64-bit or 32-bit.

## Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017

Like the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package, some programs use the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017. Maybe you need to install this one. You can find the package on [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).

Comment: maybe it's too late to respond to your solution, but thanks for the answer!